# Something went wrong when send mail via gmail using python

Tags: python, gmail

I am going to send mail via gmail smtp using python. I will add my code.

```
    gmail_user = 'mymail@gmail.com'
    gmail_password = 'xxxxxx'
    context = ssl.create_default_context()

    sent_from = gmail_user
    to = ['yyyyyyyyy@gmail.com']
    subject = 'xxxxx'
    body = 'xxxxxxxxxx'

    email_text = """\
    From: %s
    To: %s
    Subject: %s

    Car crash accident has been happened in xxxx.
    You can check the location on a Waze map with below link.
    %s
    """ % (sent_from, ", ".join(to), subject, body)

    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls(context=context)
        server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
        server.sendmail(sent_from, to, email_text)
        server.close()

        print('Email sent!')
    except:
        print('Something went wrong...')
```

But I am getting "Something went wrong...". I hope to get "Email sent!".

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Remove the last `try-except` statement, and run the code inside without them, and then tell the error what you get.

Comment: I have tried as your suggestion. Then, I have get error as below. ```Username and Password not acceptable``` But I can login with that info and check the mail.

Comment: Is the username and password correct? Because the error shows up only when it gets wrong credentials

Comment: Yes, I can login google account with gmail and password and check the mail, now.

Comment: Then in your gmail settings, you may need to enable "Access for less secure apps", also have a 2 factor authenticiation. You can check in google how to enable 2 factor authenticiation

Comment: Now, it works well. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this line -

```
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
```

To connect a server with `smtplib`, this does not do it. (I don't even know if `SMTP_SSL` exists), you should try doing this -

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
```

Also remove the `server.ehlo()` the 2nd time, it is needed  once.

So, finally, you get -

```
try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls(context=context)

    server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
    server.sendmail(sent_from, to, email_text)
    server.close()

    print('Email sent!')
except:
    print('Something went wrong...')
```

Edit -

If gmail does not recognize your username and password, then it would be because you will have to set up a 2-step authenciation, you can look at this to see [how](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop)